# Iterate Through Jquery Form Object to get inputs

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm passing a jQuery form object to a function. This function should look at all the checkboxes and find the ID attribute.

I tried the filter function. But its not seeing any input fields.

```
function templateRemove(form){

    selectedTemplateSizes = [];

    var selectedSizesCount = 0;

    form.filter(':input').each(function(i, e){
        console.log($(e));
        selectedTemplateSizes.push($(e).attr('id'));
    });

}
```

But nothing is getting added to the array and nothing gets logged in console. The call to this function is as follows:

```
 templateRemove($( "#delete-selected-form" ));
```

Am I not doing this right?

Comment: `filter` filters the current selection, you need to you `find` to look for `input`s inside the selected form

Comment: Could you put your HTML code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Find` instead of `Filter`.. , it works fine..

You can think of it this way : `Find` - Searches selected items for matched elements, whereas `Filter` removes unmatched elements from selected..

```
templateRemove($( "#delete-selected-form" ));

function templateRemove(form){

selectedTemplateSizes = [];

var selectedSizesCount = 0;

  form.find(':input').each(function(i, e){
    console.log($(e));
    selectedTemplateSizes.push($(e).attr('id'));
  });

}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/m9QqX/

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you.

Modify the function as:

```
function templateRemove(form){
    selectedTemplateSizes = [];
    var selectedSizesCount = 0;
    $(form + ' :input').each(function(i, e){
        var inputField = $(this);
        //now you can do whatever you want to do with this input field
    });
}
```

And call it as:

```
templateRemove( "#delete-selected-form" );
```

i.e, just pass the id of that element as a string and not the object itself, for easy understanding.